# C++ Optimize performance defining multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I'm having problem with time of elaboration with this code

```
vector <int>                        empty_a(120, 0);
vector <vector <int>>               empty_b(130, empty_a);
vector <vector <vector <int>>>      empty_c(220000, empty_b);
vector <vector <vector <vector <int>>>> res(3);

res[0]   =   empty_c;    
res[1]   =   empty_c;    
res[2]   =   empty_c;
```

This is the fastest way I know to define res equal to empty_c.
It take too many time. Also in :

```
vector <vector <vector <int>>>      empty_c(220000, empty_b);
```

take a lot of time.

Is there a fastest way?
I'm using also -O3 option.

Thank's

Comment: What is `res`?  And have you tried `std::move`?

Comment: That's going to do a _ton_ of allocations. Prob better to define a proper type that does the allocation at once and provides whatever access functions you need.

Comment: Four nested vectors is ..... no. Don't do that.

Comment: Also, what's the application?

Comment: Operative Research for a scenario-based application. I need to have a vector that contain for every scenario and every failure some info.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your ints are 4 bytes, this vector represent at least 13 Gigabytes.

This is ridiculously large for most applications I can think of.

Chances are you could get away with a sparse array. If not, once you get to such sizes, just allocate a single vector and use a mapping from 3D to 1D, like:

```
std::vector<int> flat(220000*120*130);
size_t At(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) { return 120*130*z + 120*y+ x;}

flat[At(x,y,z)] = someValue;
```

Or use a specialized library that will handle all of this for you.

Comment: I've never seen this method but I'm going to try it. Thank's a lot.If you know a speacilized library if you can suggest it to me.

Comment: And don't forget how many allocations and pointers are in there too due to all that nesting

Comment: By the way I'm not convinced a vector will generally over-allocate up-front; only when it runs out of capacity.

Comment: Finally, use `std::size_t` rather than `int` to ensure you have the range, and because that's already the indexing type

Comment: @Jeffrey Why does accessing an element of a `const` vector mean you need to over-allocate on construction? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know the first allocation was different,

Comment: But still, using 3- or 4- deep vector is silly. Either go flat or sparse.

Comment: If you give a vector a specific size be it on construction or with `resize` it will allocate exactly that size, only inserting or pushing elements will cause the exponential growth behaviour. As @AsteroidsWithWings said `220000*120*130` is more than `2^31` so `At` must return `size_t` and should have `size_t` parameters so ensure there is range for all the element addresses

Comment: In this way I've a vector size that is more than max size of a vector of int. Is there a solution or another way to solve? Thank's

Comment: Use a sparse vector. As you perform the OR part, anyway, you won't get all the values filled right? Only the part that have been explored?

Comment: I've:"m" scenario,"n" possible failure for each scenario,"o" node for each "m" and "n. So I've tought to save in a multidimensional vector "m x n x o" obtaininig my decisional matrix. The problem is cause by the large number of scenario that I can have studing a case with a lot of node (that make my scenario increase). So I've thout to avoid to save all result for every m, n but only for every m saving the final result. So i'm going to change my flowchart because it seems the only solutions.I need to have also good time of executions.If do you hve some suggest for me tell me. Thank's a lot.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full code, but at a very high level:
std::unordered_map<Scenario, std::vector<int>> seems a first thing to try. For each scenario you have your 120*130-sized vector. You only have a given set of scenario allocated at any time, and you allow the unloading of past scenario, when memory gets limited